# Difference between WebRequest.Create and WebRequest.CreateHttp

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am looking at the documentations between [`WebRequest.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`WebRequest.CreateHttp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382788%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to decide which I should use in my application. I do not see anything different between these two methods except `WebRequest.Create` returns a `WebRequest` and `WebRequest.CreateHttp` returns `HttpWebRequest`.

Are these two methods essentially the same except for the return value? Or do they each do something different internally?

Comment: You can look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs,cc813f29191b8611) and find out.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I never knew there was a source. Lol, I feel slow today...

Comment: That's why I posted RTFS.

Comment: Cool, I will bookmark this so I wouldn't have to ask the same question about internal differences, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebRequest.Create will return a WebRequest-derived request, based on the URL you use. If,for example, you use an FTP URL, the result will be a FileWebRequest. CreateHttp on the other hand creates an HttpWebRequest explicitly.

CreateHttp was added in .Net 4.0 while Create itself exists since 2.0.

Both methods will create an HttpWebRequest so they *can* be used interchangeably.

Comment: Okay, but would there be any performance differences between the two? I'm not able to check at the moment since I'm not at my PC that I program on.

Comment: As the source says, CreateHttp calls CreateDefault which calls Create. The same object is returned in both cases. Three calls instead of one is a negligible performance penalty.